# Debugging SQL queries in Yii. CFileLogRoute vs CWebLogRoute

Tags: php, sql, debugging, yii

After extensive search on the web, I still can't figure this out. CWebLogRoute doesn't show SQL debug info, but CFileLogRoute does. Any ideas on how to get CWebLogRoute to work? Thanks!

Here is my config file:

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myname',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'enableParamLogging'=>true,
    'enableProfiling'=>true,
),

'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, info',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, info',
        ),
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it show at least something? It's working fine on my local. Try to add `profile` into `CWebLogRoute.levels`.
BTW I prefer `CProfileLogRoute` for `sql`:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
    'enabled'=> YII_DEBUG,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I've found the Yii debug toolbar to be a fantastic add-on on a job I've been doing recently. It will display not only the SQL statements you are running (the literal ones, not the parameterized versions), but also has a lot of other information that you actually do need fairly regularly ...

You can get it here: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar/

Comment: It's for Yii1? ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is for Yii 1.1, but ported from Yii2

Answer (score 0):

what's the version of your yii framework?
and set the levels '' .

```
'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                // 'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            array( // configuration for the toolbar
              'class'=>'XWebDebugRouter',
              'config'=>'alignRight, opaque, runInDebug, fixedPos, collapsed, yamlStyle',
              // 'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, profile, info',
              'allowedIPs'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1','192.168.10.195','192\.168\.1[0-5]\.[0-9]{3}'),
            ),
        ),

    ),
```